# Two divs inside a master div, one having a fixed size

Tags: html, css

I have two divs inside a master div. The thing is, I want to be able to set a size of the master div, and for the divs inside I want to be able to set the top div to a fixed size and the div under that should fill out the rest of the area of the master div.

I will give a code example here but this does not work as the bottom div uses % to fill the rest no matter what size the master div is.

Here is a code example

```
<html lang="en"><head><style>

    .outer {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;  
        background-color:#0000FF;
    }

    .innerTop {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;   
        background-color:#008800;
    }

    .innerBottom {
        width: 400px;
        height: 100%;   
        background-color:#B6E6FB;
    }


</style>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="outer">
        <div class="innerTop">
            Upper
        </div>
        <div class="innerBottom">
            Lower
        </div>
    </div>      

</body></html>
```

Comment: i dont understand, it's doing exactly what it's supposed to, can you explain more?

Comment: try using `float:left` in the innertop and innerbottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `height: 100%` to

```
height: calc(100% - 50px);
```

at `innerBottom`.

This subtracts **50px** in height, because `innerTop` is **50px.**

If you're worried about browser compatibility, you can use:

```
height: -moz-calc(100% - 50px);
height: -o-calc(100% - 50px);
height: expression(100% - 50px);
height: calc(100% - 50px);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2Yj5u/2/)**

Comment: Here is some extra information on browser support of calc() http://caniuse.com/calc

Comment: @user1681490 `-moz-calc`, `expression`

Comment: Excellent!  knew there was a pretty easy solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute positioning to position the top `div`, and then apply an appropriate margin to the bottom div so they don't overlap.

Also ensure you apply `box-sizing: border-box;` to all elements so calculations are done properly for this layout.

```
* { box-sizing: border-box }

.outer {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;  
    background-color:#0000FF;
}

.innerTop {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;   
    background-color:#008800;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}

.innerBottom {
    width: 400px;
    margin-top:50px;
    height: 100%;   
    background-color:#B6E6FB;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qDgS8/